# Set AD users extensionAttibute value using powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I need to change the users **extensionAttribute8** value to 1

when I am trying to get the existing value for this attribute using below command, I am getting other values but not the specific attribute value

- Output Example:

```
DistinguishedName : AAAAA
Enabled           : True
GivenName         : AAAAA
Name              : AAAAA
ObjectClass       : user
ObjectGUID        : 1ed23b21-afa9-4d2d-9c64-d3278f93af50
SamAccountName    : AAAAAA
SID               : AAAAAA
Surname           : AAAA
UserPrincipalName : AAAAA
```

```
 $ThisUser = Get-ADUser -Identity $User -Properties extensionAttribute8
 #   Set-ADUser –Identity $ThisUser -add @{"extensionattribute8"="1"}
```

Please do let me know what is wrong here. Is there something I am missing

Comment: "I am getting other values but not the specific attribute value" - what kind of values?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: Sorry for that. updated the post

Comment: `-Replace @{extensionAttribute8 = "1"}` instead of `-Add`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: I will check this. and one more thing. I have 2 different OU's where I have to search users based on ID (e.g. if starts with WA then A if starts with WB then B). how to add the `searchBase` in this command? when I am adding `searchbase` I am getting error `Get-ADUser : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command is correct  and retrieves the user required attribute

```
Get-ADUser -Identity $User -Properties extensionAttribute8
```

HOWEVER if the attribute isnt populated it won't be returned.

To set the attribute I use:

```
Set-ADUser -Identity $User -Replace @{"extensionattribute8"="1"}
```

Use "Replace" as it will work if the value is already populated rather than Add, which will only add to an already populated value.